# How to Create MSSQL database user with ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to create MSSQL database user and then grant a database access ( owner privileges ) to this user using ARM templates?

Answer (score 1):

Not in the current iteration of ARM. [Here is what is supported with SQL server ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers).

If you're fixed on using db user/pass to talk to the database, try a [powershell script as part of your CI/CD pipeline](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/04/12/creating-accounts-on-azure-sql-database-through-powershell-automation/). But you could also look at [Azure AD cert-based auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#azure-ad-token) or [Managed Service Identity (MSI) instead](https://winterdom.com/2017/10/19/azure-sql-auth-with-msi).

Comment: Just a note on ARM template support. It seems it is still not possible to create an MSI connected user using ARM alone. It still needs fiddling in the database after creation. The MSI link above explains as much as well. Here is another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62581121/can-non-administrative-users-be-provisioned-in-azure-sql-via-an-arm-template